# add Angular Controller in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework, requirejs

Problem: I try to add controllers by array to my app module in angular.
My setup is Ionic + Angular + requireJS.

### controllers.js

```
/*global define, require */

var controllers;
define(function (require) {

'use strict';

var angular = require('angular'),
[...]
controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services', 'app.config']);

controllers.controller('SidebarMenuCtrl', require('controllers/SidebarMenuCtrl'));
controllers.controller('DefaultCtrl', require('controllers/DefaultCtrl'));

[...]
```

Now my problem part:

```
var ctrls = ['aboutCtrl', 'loginCtrl', 'infoCtrl'];
for (var k in ctrls) {
    controllers.controller(ctrls[k], require('controllers/' + ctrls[k]));
}
```

---

requirejs now says

> Module name "controllers/aboutCtrl" has not been loaded yet for context

and for every other controller I try to load within loop.

The controllers I loaded above are working fine.
So I'm shure it has not to do with requirejs directly.

---

[edit]: I now kind of fixed it by requiring the file before using it in `.controller()` using requirejs' callback:

```
for (var k in ctrls) {
            require(['controllers/'+ctrls[k]], function (c) {
                controllers.controller(ctrls[k], c);
            });
        }
```

---

The question still persists: Why does requirejs not do its job like above the loop?

Comment: It's kinda hard to say without seeing the code in context. My best guess at this point is that the controllers are case sensitive and they actually are "AboutCtrl", "LoginCtrl", "InfoCtrl" but it's hard to say conclusively.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea on a number of levels.  Driving your app via require instead of angular components isn't good structure.  In addition, instead of dynamically adding controllers you should consider dynamically adding directives.

Comment: i now edited my question.
@sourdoughdetzel I checked capitalisation multiple times. No error there.

Comment: @DavidL I'm new to angularjs, I'll look into directives, but there are some reasons, why I try to archieve this.

Comment: Explaining your reasoning would help you get better answers also

Comment: @DavidL while I agree, it's not always clear WHY someone is doing something, so answering their question is usually the first thing I try to do. Then I'll make some suggestions as to different/better ways to do it.

Comment: @sourdoughdetzel I understand why that is your course of action.  Mine is to try to prevent people from painful mistakes that will cause an increasing number of problems down the road.  Also, note, it is just a comment, not an answer.  If there were more context I might have a decent answer but as it stands right now, answering this question would only result in a temporary fix to a larger issue and that's never my intention.